# Power Series of a compressible flow function

Tags: power-series, fluid-dynamics

In compressible flow there is a formula for an angle:
$$
\tan \left(\theta \right)=\frac{2\cot \left(\beta \right)\left(M_1\sin ^2\left(\beta \right)-1\right)}{M_1\left(k+\cos \left(2\beta \right)\right)+2}
$$
For a finite $\theta$ it can be shown that this formula can be written as a this power series:
$$
\sin \left(\beta \right)=\sin \left(\mu \right)+\frac{k+1}{4\cos \left(\mu \right)}\tan \left(\theta \right)+.....\:+\:O\left(tan^2\left(\theta \right)\right)+...
$$
Where $\mu = sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{M_1})$

So im looking for a exact way to write this power series in the form:
$$
\sin(\beta) =  \sum... 
$$
Forumla can be found here https://slidetodoc.com/shock-waves-and-expansion-waves-1-shock-wave/

I want to use it in a numerical project im currently working on.

Comment: Edited and I hope it is now clearer

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan \left(\theta \right)=\frac{2\cot \left(\beta \right)\left(M\sin ^2\left(\beta \right)-1\right)}{M\left(k+\cos \left(2\beta \right)\right)+2}$$

$$\color{blue}{s=\sin(\beta)}\implies \tan \left(\theta \right)=\frac{2 \sqrt{1-s^2} \left(M s^2-1\right)}{s \left(M \left(k+1-2 s^2\right)+2\right)} \tag 1$$ Rewrite $(1)$ as
$$\tan \left(\theta \right) \Big[s \left(M \left(k+1-2 s^2\right)+2\right)\Big]-2 \sqrt{1-s^2} \left(M s^2-1\right)=0 \tag 2$$ Now, make
$$s=\sin(\beta)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\tan^k \left(\theta \right)+O\left(\tan^{n+1} \left(\theta \right)\right)$$ Replace in $(2)$ that you will expand
as a Taylor series around $\tan \left(\theta \right)=0$.

Now cancel each coefficient of $\tan^k \left(\theta \right)$  **one at the time**.

**Edit**

To make the calculations simpler let $A=\frac 12M(k+1)$ to rewrite $(2)$
$$\tan \left(\theta \right) \Big[(A+1) s -M s^3\Big]- \sqrt{1-s^2} \left(M s^2-1\right)=0 \tag 3$$

This should give
$$a_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\qquad a_1=\frac{A}{2 \sqrt{(M-1) M}} \qquad a_2=  \frac{A\Big[-4(M-1)+A (M+1) \Big]}{8 (M-1)^2 \sqrt{M}}$$
$$a_3=\frac{A\Big[8(M-1)^2- 4\left(2 M^2- M-1\right)A+(4 M+1)A^2\Big]}{16 (M-1)^{7/2} \sqrt{M} }$$ The next coefficient become to be really long and messy to be typed here.

Comment: I dont really understand the way you have written this formula. Could you write it in a summation form?

Comment: @Lopehert. Which formula ? You want $s=\sin(\beta)$ as a function of $x=\tan(\theta)$, don't you ? These are the steps and I tried to make steps very detailed. You can write $s=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i\,x^i$ if you wish. The process will stay the same.

Comment: If you could write $sin(\beta) = \sum$ and write out whats inside the sum in a way i could understand it $ \sum \tan(\theta)*5*\alpha ...$ etc and not in the way you did